# Setting website config to blank, Magento uses default

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, configuration, ce-1.6.2.0, scope, ce-1.7.0.1

Magento doesn't seem to like me setting blank config values at `website` or `store` level.

Steps to reproduce (1.6.2.0, 1.7.0.1, 1.7.0.2)

```
1) change config scope to website
2) untick use default next to 'default welcome message'
3) clear the text in the field
4) save
```

At this stage Magento will re-tick the use default box, however, it has saved my blank value. The next time I save this config page the config value from the default level is used.

This functionality was not present in 1.4, and I don't have 1.5 to test.

My question is, how do I create blank config values at the website or store level?

---

Update

In version 1.7.02 the code looks like this:

```
            $path = (string)$element->config_path;
            if (empty($path)) {
                $path = $section->getName() . '/' . $group->getName() . '/' . $fieldPrefix . $element->getName();
            } elseif (strrpos($path, '/') > 0) {
                // Extend config data with new section group
                $groupPath = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, '/'));
                if (!isset($configDataAdditionalGroups[$groupPath])) {
                    $this->_configData = $this->_configDataObject->extendConfig(
                        $groupPath,
                        false,
                        $this->_configData
                    );
                    $configDataAdditionalGroups[$groupPath] = true;
                }
            }
```

And it uses `empty()` to evaluate the string.

Does anyone have a suggestion to modify this code to allow empty strings that I specify to override the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from here:
`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form::initFields()`

**[For Magento 1.7.0.0]**
Around line 295 there is this piece of code:

```
if (isset($this->_configData[$path])) {
    $data = $this->_configData[$path];
    $inherit = false;
} else {
    $data = $this->_configRoot->descend($path);
    $inherit = true;
}
```

This determines if the 'Use website/Use default value' checkbox is checked or not.
The problem is that when a value is empty `$this->_configData[$path]` is `null`.  And the function `isset()` returns `true` only if the parameter exists and is not null.
If you replace
`if (isset($this->_configData[$path])) {`
with
`if (array_key_exists($path, $this->_configData)) {`
it should work.

**[For Magento 1.7.0.2]**
In 1.7.0.2 version the code from above was moved in `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data::getConfigDataValue()`

It's a similar piece of code and the solution is the same:
At line 388 there is this:

```
if (isset($configData[$path])) {
```

that should be replaced by this:

```
if (array_key_exists($path, $configData)) {
```

Comment: +1 for being in the right direction, which version does your code example come from? 1.7.0.2 is different. See updated question

Comment: i checked for 1.7.0.0 but there is no difference in 1.7.0.2. Below the code you posted in the question is the code I posted in the answer. Changing what I suggested should fix the problem, but try not to do it in the core file directly. Copy it in the local folder or extend the class.

Comment: Im not a noob, but your code is not in my file! I must not have the version I think I do.

Comment: well ...damn. It IS different for 1.7.0.2. My bad. I updated the answer with instructions on what to do for v1.7.0.2